# How to escape a "." in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, escaping

For some reason a backslash doesn't work. This is for a file with delimited data.

Right now this is my expression is:

```
output=$(awk -F '|''BEGIN {count=0;} $2==Smith {count++; print count $1}' customer)

echo $output
```

gives me

```
11001 21002 31003
```

I want the output to look like:

```
1. 1001
2. 1002
3. 1003
```

This is my attempt..

```
awk -F '|''BEGIN {count=0;} $2==Smith {count++; print count, '\.', $1}' customer
```

Comment: The newlines are in `$output`, but are removed by the shell when you don't quote `$output`. Use `echo "$output"`.

Comment: did you try `print count, \'.\', $1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the statement with double quotes:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {count=0;} $2==Smith {count++; print count". "$1}' customer
```

Comment: No need for newline. `print` inserts it for you.

Comment: Ah that's right. I was trying to save into a variable and echo it. Thanks a lot.